# UITableView not scroll first cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have two section in my `UITabelView`. My first cell (in first section) represents some caption. Can I have this cell not move when I scroll `UITableView`, so other content (cells) will scroll but not first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this isn't supported. Everything in a table view scrolls with the table view. The closest thing resembling what you want is section headers in a plain table. The section header stays at the top of screen as the section scrolls but it stays with its section.

Your only option is to use a `UIViewController` instead of a `UITableViewController`. Add your caption view to the top and then add your own `UITableView` below the caption view. You will need to hook everything up so the view controller works like a table view controller.